# Can't see tables after config hibernate to myeclipse?

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to config hibernate 3.3 on myeclipse, I have a `.jar` file that contains my tables. But after the configuration ends, I can't see the list of my tables in DB Browser. I don't know whether I have configured it the wrong way or something else.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for a guide on how to ask a good question. Please post at least your Hibernate config so we can try and work out what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The configuration was right, but I had to create all tables! which I didn't consider after creating those tables.